# Performance optimization in message delivery and consuming mechanism WSO2 MB 3.1.0

Tags: optimization, wso2, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker

How will I be able to do a `Performance Tuning` in `WSO2 Message Broker`? I did go through [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Message+Publisher+and+Consumer+Performance) document which explains about modifying the parameter values in the `broker.xml` which ideally did improve the performance of message delivery plus consumption.

These were the parameters which I changed :

- ringBufferSize
- windowSize
- contentReadBatchSize
- bufferSize

Is there anything else that I should change in order to improve the optimization? What I wanted to know is that, is there any other way available other than this for `performance tuning`? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are few other things you can try out to improve the performance in WSO2 products in terms of OS level, JVM level and Carbon platform level you can find more details at [1]. There are also some details related to product level tuning in terms of clustered environment, tuning flow control could be found in [2] and [3] respectively. Also, database level performance tuning details can be found at [4]. Hope this will be helpful for you to improve the performance.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Performance+Tuning+Guide

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Clustering+Performance

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Tuning+Flow+Control

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Database+Performance

Cheers,
Pubudu.